# Setting breakpoints on all lines of VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, testing

I need to test a very long program that takes many decisions based on live data from an online database. So it is unfeasible to use step in (F8) for an entire run of the program.

I was wondering if there was a way of setting a breakpoint on EVERY line of code of the project. Then when I have tested that line I can clear it and keep running. At the end I will know what part of the program was not tested because it will still have break points.

Any ideas on how to SET EVERY LINE OF A VBA PROJECT TO A BREAKPOINT?

Comment: I would suggest as an alternative adding a debug output scheme to give you intermediate results at key points in the code.  Then you can set up a scenario where you know what each of those intermediate results SHOULD be and compare against your debug output.

Comment: Also, setting a breakpoint on every line of code would force you to click one of the "continue running my code" buttons every time anyway (not to mention you'd have to clear the breakpoint as well), so I don't see any advantage.  If you're unsure of which parts of your code the tests might visit, the debug output is still probably your best bet.  I have a self-instancing singleton Logger class that I could provide as an answer which supports multiple outputs (CSV file, textbox, message box) and custom error levels (Debug, Info, Warning, Error) if it would interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature of the VBA Editor. Instead use "Watches"